WIndows 10 host always requests DHCPv6 address
My Windows 10 PC is connected to a dual stack (IPv4 & IPv6) network. After checking the Router Advertisements of this network, I saw that no RA flag is set in its router advertisements, although there is a DHCPv6 service running on that network.
Based on the configuration above, I would expect that hosts would not request an DHCPv6 address, since the M-flag is not set. This expected behaviour is verified on a raspberry-pi device connected to the same network, which gets no IPv6 (SLAAC is also disabled on this network).
However, my Windows 10 PC seems to ignore the RA flags and requests a DHCPv6 address. Since there is a DHCPv6 server on the network, this leads to getting a DHCPv6 address anyway.
Is this strange behaviour by Windows 10 expected? Is this documented somewhere that Windows hosts behave that way? Isn't that in contrast with the IPv6 RFCs?

It doesn't look like the relevant IPv6 RFCs prohibit using DHCPv6 in this situation.

For example, RFC 2462 only says that the host should start using DHCPv6 if ManagedFlag (the most recently seen M-flag) changes from FALSE to TRUE, but then explicitly states that the host should not stop using DHCPv6 if the flag becomes FALSE, and that there is no specific meaning associated with the flag in itself – only with its "FALSE→TRUE" change.

This text was completely removed from the revised RFC 4862.


Additionally, RFC 2462 says that a host may use both methods simultaneously, and even seems to require the host to start DHCPv6 if there are no routers available. (I think this was also softened in RFC 4862.)


So effectively the M flag is only a hint as to the availability to DHCPv6, not an off switch, and this behavior doesn't seem to be unique to Windows; for example, systemd-networkd has it as an option.
